# Use Hugo to render html files

Tags: html, go, static-site, static-pages, hugo

I am using Hugo http://hugo.spf13.com/overview/introduction to render a folder with html/css/js files as localhost in my laptop.

I have html files in `/content` and all js/css/img files in `/static` folder

This is content in `config.toml`

```
baseurl = "http://localhost"
contentdir = "content"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "my new hugo site"
```

I did `hugo server` and it rendered `/public` folder just fine. But all .html files now turning into .xml files and I cannot open them in browser like `http://localhost:1313/index.html` or so.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup a theme yet? Without a theme, Hugo will render files as XML, if you read the documentation on themes, that should give you what you need.

Comment: No I haven't done theme. Which theme should I use and what in the command line?

Comment: The documentation should be enough to get you going: http://hugo.spf13.com/themes/overview

Comment: The link in the comment does not work

Answer (score 1):

First you have to clone themes from github.com/spf13/hugoThemes

In my case I did'nt have git install in my test machine here are the things that I did:

1) Download theme from github.com/spf13/hugoThemes

2) Extract theme to /path/themes

3) Run hugo --theme='themename'

Comment: Correct link is https://github.com/spf13/hugoThemes. So if I don't care what theme but just want .html to work, do I pick "html5" one?

Comment: Yeah pick html5 then follow some instruction on html5 theme github page

Comment: Once you have settled on a theme, add it to the configuration file `config.toml` so you don't have to use --theme when running hugo.